FortiClient VPN keeps crashing my computer (Linux)
FortiClient VPN that I use at work keeps crashing/freezing my computer, forcing me to hold down the power button and restart.
If I click SAML Login to connect to the VPN via FortiClient GUI, it will work for 3-4 minutes before my whole system freezes. When i'm back in the PC doesn't recognize any networks (even though I use an ethernet cable), and I'll have to manually delete all connections before I restart again and everything works like normal.
I get no error logs.
I am using Ubuntu 24.04 LTS, even though FortiNet doesn't officially support this. The workaround: remove two dependencies (libappindicator1 and libayatana-appindicator1) in the .deb when installing using apt.
My FortiClient VPN version is 7.4.0.1636.
Any ideas/solutions?
Thanks in advance :)
